# Lifetime error on Storage Mutate

Tags: storage

I have a function that updates my Listing struct in DoubleMap Storage. How can I mutate the storage with given optional params?

```rust
pub fn update_listing(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    property_id: T::Hash,
    is_active: Option<bool>,
    content: Option<Content<T::MaxContentLength>>,
) -> DispatchResult {
    let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    ensure!(Listings::<T>::get(&property_id, &who).is_some(), Error::<T>::ListingNotFound);

    Listings::<T>::mutate(&property_id, &who, |o_listing| {
        let listing = o_listing.as_mut().unwrap();
        if let Some(is_active) = is_active {
            listing.is_active = is_active;
        }
        if let Some(content) = content {
            listing.content = content;
        }
        Some(listing)
    });

    Self::deposit_event(Event::ListingUpdated(property_id, who));
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> pallets/listing/src/lib.rs:131:5
    |
123 |             Listings::<T>::mutate(&property_id, &who, |mut o_listing| {
    |                                                        -------------- return type of closure is std::option::Option<&'2 mut Listing<<T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxContentLength>>
    |                                                        |
    |                                                        has type `&'1 mut std::option::Option<Listing<<T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxContentLength>>`
...
131 |                 Some(listing)
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
Listings::<T>::mutate(&property_id, &who, |listing| {
    // you don't need to use `as_mut` here. listing is already a `&mut _`
    if let Some(is_active) = is_active {
        listing.is_active = is_active;
    }
    if let Some(content) = content {
        listing.content = content;
    }
    // you can not return a local reference to outside, take the ownership first 
    // Some(listing.to_owned())
    // or
    Some(listing.clone())
});
```

Furthermore, you could use `try_mutate` or `get/insert`. While the `listing` is not changed, you could save one DB write cost.

---

Update for the `OptionQuery`:

```rust
Listings::<T>::mutate(&property_id, &who, |maybe_listing| {
    maybe_listing.as_mut().map(|listing| {
        if let Some(is_active) = is_active {
            listing.is_active = is_active;
        }
        if let Some(content) = content {
            listing.content = content;
        }

        Some(listing.clone())
    })
});
```

Comment: That works well for `ValueQuery` but since I use `OptionQuery`, `listing` is an `Option`. How could I use this in my case?

Comment: I've just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mutate`, I get and edit the data and then insert it.

```rust
let mut listing =
    Listings::<T>::get(&property_id, &who).ok_or(Error::<T>::ListingNotFound)?;

if let Some(status) = status {
    listing.status = status;
}
if let Some(content) = content {
    listing.content = content;
}

Listings::<T>::insert(&property_id, &who, listing);
```