# How to mutate a `StorageDoubleMap` value?

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, storage, frame, storagemap

I have `StorageDoubleMap` for `ERC1155 balances u32 -> AccountId -> u32`;

How can I mutate this map like `balances[1][SomeAccountId] -= 4`?

Comment: Please check out API docs. in crates.parity.io

Comment: Also, check this https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4395/lifetime-error-on-storage-mutate/4399#comment4624_4399

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you would use this syntax of [try_mutate](https://docs.rs/frame-support/3.0.0/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageDoubleMap.html#tymethod.try_mutate)

similar to e.g.

```
<Balances<T>>::try_mutate(&asset_id, &owner, |balance| {
    *balance -= 4;
    Ok(())
})
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend Lana's answer, you can just use `mutate` in the case that your operation is infallible:

```rust
<Balances<T>>::mutate(&asset_id, &owner, |balance| {
    *balance = balance.saturating_sub(4);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to search in the Substrate repository first.

---

[`/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs::mutate`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/badc92ac20dbf006595a6af9418da9942527cbd7/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs#L647-L651)

```rust
AuthoredBlocks::<T>::mutate(&current_session, author, |authored| *authored += 1);
```

[`/frame/assets/src/lib.rs::try_mutate`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/badc92ac20dbf006595a6af9418da9942527cbd7/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L789-L792)

```rust
Account::<T, I>::try_mutate(id, &who, |maybe_account| -> DispatchResult {
    maybe_account.as_mut().ok_or(Error::<T, I>::NoAccount)?.is_frozen = true;
    Ok(())
})?;
```

---

There are still a lot of examples. Check the Substrate repository.